# exception when altering table

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo

I am getting the following exception when trying to alter a table:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE instagram_picture_tag ADD CONSTRAINT FK_67B371CDBAD26311 FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES instagram_tag (id) ON DELETE CASCADE':            

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Shopious`.`#sql-2e38_dd33a`, CONSTRAINT `FK_67B371CDBAD26311` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`)   
  REFERENCES `instagram_tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

how do I fix something like this? I am trying to add a constraint on an existing table that already exists, but it seems that it conflicts with the foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

Well the error means that the check that is run on the foreign key fails and can't update the table so check your foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have data in your instagram_picture_tag table? If so you should check for all rows that the tag_id column is null or it references an existing instagram_tag.

If your data is not breaking the FK, check that instagram_picture_tag.tag_id and instagram_tag.id have exactly the same type.

Comment: As @Jordi said you have to check the type or the existing instagram_tag, other solution (not very professional) is to extract all your database as sql file then delete all foreign key from the file , after that delete the insert statement from instagram_picture_tag and instagram_tag if that doesn't matter then recreate the database and import the sql file finaly make an update to database using console.